# generating 50 random float arraylist value unique

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, random

I'm trying to write code that stores 50 randomly generated floating point numbers in an ArrayList. Use a regular for-loop to cycle through the values and remove any that are less than 0.5. Then use a for-each loop to print out the values that remain.

this is my code so far and I don't know where to go from here...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class fiftyFloats {

    public static void main (String [] args) { 

        //create a reference for the array list 
        ArrayList <Float> vals; 

        //reserve space for it in memeory 
        vals = new ArrayList <Float> (50);

        for (int i = 0; i<vals.size(); i++){
            i = new Float
        }

        for (Integer atPos: vals) { 
            System.out.println(vals.toString()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but there are no randomly generated numbers, just some loop that wont compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this depending on how you want to generate a "random" number.

java.util.Random has some functions that can be used, including "nextFloat" which returns a random values between 0 and 1 of the float type.

so

```
ArrayList <Float> vals = new ArrayList<>();
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
     vals.add(rand.nextFloat());
}
```

Then it should be easy enough to loop through the list again and remove any number that doesn't meet your criterion. You don't need to reserve 50 spots up front in an ArrayList, that's one of the benefits of using it, that you can dynamically add to it.

Your loop as is won't work. You already defined "i" as an integer in your loop code, now you're trying to create a float with the same name. You can use "i" inside your loop, but it is going to be the "i" that you specified at "int i = 0;"

Overall it seems like you're very new and don't understand some core things about java, like how variables work. Consulting a tutor/teacher/basic text would probably helpy ou a lot.

Comment: I am very new to java and thank you so much for your thorough answer

Answer (score 0):

1. To generate a random number you need to use the Random class.

**NOTE** - random.nextFloat() will only generate a number between 0.0 and 1 if you want to include larger numbers you will need to multiply it

2. The integer you are using to control the for loop cannot be reassigned to a float within the loop
3. You don't need to put arrayList.toString() in a loop

   ```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Random;

   public class fiftyFloats {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   ArrayList<Float> vals = new ArrayList<Float>();

   Float randomNum;
   Random rand = new Random();
   for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
       randomNum = rand.nextFloat();
       if (randomNum > 0.5) {
           vals.add(randomNum);
       }
   }

   System.out.println(vals.toString());

   }}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Since the float values you need are not **quoted** between min and max then you can use nano time

Example:

```
List <Float> vals = new ArrayList <Float> (50);

for (int i = 0; i<vals.size(); i++){
    vals.add (System.current/100.0f);
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do here:

```
    //create a reference for the array list 
    ArrayList<Float> vals;

    //reserve space for it in memeory 
    vals = new ArrayList<Float>(50);

    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        vals.add(rand.nextFloat());
    }

    for (Float val : vals) {
        System.out.println(val.toString());
    }
```

**Some things to point out in your original code:**

```
    Float fl = new Float(2.2);

    //create a reference for the array list 
    ArrayList<Float> vals;

    // Here, you've set the _Capacity_, not the size.
    vals = new ArrayList<Float>(50); // vals.size() => 0

    // Based on above, you are essentially saying "never do these things"
    // -> for (int i = 0; i < 0; i++)
    for (int i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++) {

        // this, if a valid expression, would have an incompatible type
        // since i is of type int.

        // if you were to use this, you would need to use a constructor such as
        // new Float(1.2).

        i = new Float

    }

    // In this enhanced loop, you are assigning a value from ArrayList vals
    // to atPos, not the position. Since ArrayList is of type Float,
    // atPos is a Float.
    for (Integer atPos : vals) {
        System.out.println(vals.toString());

    }
```